# Microsoft Remote Evaluation Service

Tags: remote, licensing, evaluation

Microsoft used to offer a service where you could connect to an evaluation system via Remote Desktop and temporarily evaluate the new software.

I believe this service existed 5+ years ago and Microsoft has since moved onto only offering Virtual Machines for software evaluations.

What is the name of that offering and where could I find some information about what it was?

Comment: Should you not be asking Microsoft about this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/events/vlabs/default.mspx